# How to condense dataset with too many NAs in R?

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset that I'd like to condense down to one row per item, but as of now, it is filled with a lot of NAs so that each row about the item has one piece of information. A sample of it looks as follows:

```
ID     Title             Composer           Lyricist          Illustrator
a0018  My Western Rose   NA                 NA                NA
a0018  NA                Lincoln, Harry J.  NA                NA
a0018  NA                NA                 Vandersloot, F.W. NA
a0018  NA                NA                 NA                Dittmar, W.J.
```

How can I get this so that there is only one row for each ID that has all of the information?

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr::summarise_at` can be achieved as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Title:Illustrator), funs(.[!is.na(.)])) %>%
  data.frame()

#      ID           Title          Composer          Lyricist   Illustrator
# 1 a0018 My Western Rose Lincoln, Harry J. Vandersloot, F.W. Dittmar, W.J
#
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"ID     Title             Composer           Lyricist          Illustrator
a0018  'My Western Rose'   NA                 NA                NA
a0018  NA                'Lincoln, Harry J.'  NA                NA
a0018  NA                NA                 'Vandersloot, F.W.' NA
a0018  NA                NA                 NA                'Dittmar, W.J.'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  the `tidyverse` suite of packages, try

```
clean_df <- df %>%
   gather(key, value) %>%
   drop_na(value) %>%
   gather(key, value)
```

If you aren't familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), it takes the result of the previous function and plugs it in as the first argument in the next function.  Primarily, it just makes it easier to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want. The tribble line is just to get the data into a reproducible data.frame, so you would just use your data.frame name instead of 'dat'.

```
dat <- tribble(
~ID,     ~Title,             ~Composer,           ~Lyricist,          ~Illustrator,
"a0018",  "My Western Rose",   NA,                 NA,                NA,
"a0018",  NA,                "Lincoln, Harry J.",  NA,                NA,
"a0018",  NA,                NA,                 "Vandersloot, F.W.", NA,
"a0018" , NA,                NA,                 NA,                "Dittmar, W.J."
)
clean_df <- dat %>%
gather(key, value, na.rm=T) %>%
unique() %>% 
spread(key, value) %>% 
select(ID, Title, Composer, Lyricist, Illustrator)
```

Comment: MKR has the right answer. Mine only works with one ID. :(